# How do I retrieve the currently Logged in email address and send a Mail in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
    if ($user->save()) {
        $data = DB::table('posts')->get();
        $data = array( 
            'description' => $request->description,
            'Location'=> $request->Location,
            'lat' => $request->lat,
            'lng' => $request->lng,
        );
        Mail::send('contact',$data,function($message) use($data) {
            //Mail has been sent but both the From and To email address are same 
            // i.e. abc@gmail.com not Logged in user's email
            $message->from(Auth::user()->email);
            //to email address which i have hard coded
            $message->to('abc@gmail.com');
            $message->subject($data['Location']);
        });
        return redirect('/index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your email address in session when  login and retrieve fro session when you send mail

Comment: @Nazmul Hasan I need the email address currently logged in but in the document I saw we can only retriew all the email address not the logged in user's!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($user->save()) {
    $data = DB::table('posts')->get();
    $data = array( 
        'description' => $request->description,
        'Location'=> $request->Location,
        'lat' => $request->lat,
        'lng' => $request->lng,
    );
    if (Auth::check()
    {
     $data['email'] = User::whereId(Auth::user()->id)->value('email');
    }
    if(empty($data['email'])) return false;
    Mail::send('contact',$data,function($message) use($data) {
        //Mail has been sent but both the From and To email address are same 
        // i.e. abc@gmail.com not Logged in user's email
        $message->from($data['email']);
        //to email address which i have hard coded
        $message->to($data['email']);
        $message->subject($data['Location']);
    });
    return redirect('/index');
}
```

}

Comment: I have tried the above code @Nazul Hasan   getting the error as  (1/1) ErrorException

Undefined variable: email

Comment: I am getting confused about your code from and to email address can u explain me... @Nazmul Hasan